# Server-side generated video with custom texture - Where to start?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am working on a project in which a user can upload an image and then after uploading the image, a video is generated and then displayed, containing the image which was uploaded as some sort of texture/mask. (Like they do in [Elf Yourself](http://www.elfyourself.com/)).

The original video should contain some sort of placeholder for the image to allow it to move around and be transformed on a matrix.

I'm not really sure where to start off or how I should even call such a merging/blending process in the first place.

A few requirements I've came up with so far:
 - The server runs PHP
 - I am able to use GD, Imagick and FFMPEG

Regards